# c++ getline reads entire file

Tags: c++, file, text, getline

I'm using std::getline() to read from a text file, line by line. However, the first call to getline is reading in the entire file! I've also tried specifying the delimeter as '\n' explicitly. Any ideas why this might be happening?

My code:

```
std::ifstream serialIn;
...
serialIn.open(argv[3]);
...
std::string tmpStr;
std::getline(serialIn, tmpStr, '\n');
// All 570 lines in the file is in tmpStr!
...
std::string serialLine;
std::getline(serialIn, serialLine);
// serialLine == "" here
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008. The text file has 570 lines (I'm viewing it in Notepad++ fwiw).

**Edit:** I worked around this problem by using Notepad++ to convert the line endings in my input text file to "Windows" line endings. The file was written with '\n' at the end of each line, using c++ code. Why would getline() require the Windows line endings (\r\n)?? Does this have to do with character width, or Microsoft implementation?

Comment: Can you post the first 10 lines of the file please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure getline() defaults to `'\n'` as a delimiter.. I don't see why carriage return would affect it.

Comment: Standard I/O library functions read and write the line-endings for the platform.  Programs built against a Windows C or C++ runtime therefore expect Windows line-endings (shocking!).

Comment: Thanks, jamesdlin. I think a link to documentation that confirms this behavior would be more helpful than sarcasm.

Answer (score 6):

Just guessing, but could your file have Unix line-endings and you're running on Windows?

Comment: +1 Just to explain... on UNIX/Linux, a single linefeed character (ASCII code 10) delimits lines, whereas on Windows both a carriage return (13) and a linefeed are expected. So, if your file only has linefeeds they may not be recognised as line delimiters by C++, even though some editors will recognise them and show you the file content with intended line breaks.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why would getline() require the Windows line endings (\r\n) when its documentation says that it uses the '\n' (Unix) line delimeter alone? And furthermore I explicitly set the delimeter to '\n' to make sure. Are you saying there is indeed a discrepancy between the documentation and how it really works? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the *newline* you see in code (`'\n'`) with the actual *line-ending representation* for the platform (some combination of carriage-return (CR) and linefeed (LF) bytes).

The standard I/O library functions automatically convert line-endings for your platform to and from conceptual newlines for text-mode streams (the default).  See [What's the difference between text and binary I/O?](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/textvsbinary.html)  from the comp.lang.c FAQ. (Although that's from the C FAQ, the concepts apply to C++ as well.) Since you're on Windows, the standard I/O functions by default write newlines as CR-LF and expect CR-LF for newlines when reading.

If you don't want these conversions done and would prefer to see the raw, unadulterated data, then you should set your streams to binary mode.  In binary mode, `\n` corresponds to just LF, and `\r` corresponds to just CR.

In C, you can specify binary mode by passing `"b"` as one of the flags to `fopen`:

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb"); // Open a file for reading in binary mode.
```

In C++:

```
 std::ifstream in;
 in.open(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

or:

```
 std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
```