# c++ getline reads entire file in Windows

Tags: c++, getline

This looks like a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152311/c-getline-reads-entire-file), however I think my case might actually be a bit different. The code is as below:

```
void readOmronResults(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inFile(fileName);
    ofstream testRead("test_read.txt");

    string line;
    //getline(inFile, line);
    //cout << line << endl;
    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        testRead << line << endl;
    }


    inFile.close();
    testRead.close();

    cout << "Finished reading omron results" << endl;
}
```

testRead is just used for debugging. The input file is a .csv file which looks like:

```
    IMAGE,RIGHT_EYE_IN_X,RIGHT_EYE_IN_Y,RIGHT_EYE_OUT_X,RIGHT_EYE_OUT_Y,LEFT_EYE_IN_X,LEFT_EYE_IN_Y,LEFT_EYE_OUT_X,LEFT_EYE_OUT_Y
    0001_2m_-15P_-10V_-10H,2386,1627,2171,1613,2754,1623,3009,1583
    0001_2m_-15P_-10V_-15H,2377,1620,2171,1606,2750,1611,3003,1574
    0001_2m_-15P_-10V_-5H,2376,1614,2166,1599,2752,1609,3012,1577
           ...
```

If I run the above code, the output in test_read.txt is exactly the same as it is in the input file. However if I restore the two commented out lines, the console window shows all the lines in the input file( repeatedly from the second line) and the test_read.txt is empty. From the linked post I guess it probably has something to do with the difference of line endings in different operating systems. My operating system is Windows and according to my text editor the original input file is Mac-OS style. But if it is because of this, why is the original code (with the two lines commented out) able to give a correct result?

My IDE is Visual Studio 2012 and my machine is 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My operating system is Windows and according to my text editor the original input file is Mac-OS style.

Yes, this is the problem. Windows' C and C++ standard libraries will assume that text files use the Windows line ending, `U+0D U+0A`.

"Mac OS style" is an odd thing for the text editor to say, because the other line ending in common use `U+0A` which is common to the entire Unix family including Linux. Long ago, Mac OS used `U+0D` which makes the phrase "Mac OS style" ambiguous and anachronistic.

> But if it is because of this, why is the original code (with the two lines commented out) able to give a correct result?

It didn't. Both versions of the program treat the file as if it contains one very long line.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! The original code didn't give the correct answer. The editor automatically converts the line endings according to what are used in Mac OS and I thought it was generated by multiple getline calls. Thank you!

Comment: @eaglesky Your editor actually converted a file to use carriage return endings? Pathological. What is it called? I've seen Eclipse do this under some circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

If they are Mac OS endings `'\r'`, according to the docs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ this behaviour is not surprising.

Paraphrasing the docs: when not giving a delimiter, `getline` will ready until a newline (`'\n'`) character is encountered.

Comment: OS X uses '\n', the same as other unixes. '\r' line endings are for the classic Mac OS.

Comment: Ugh. Please don't use cplusplus.com, they have terrible fact-checking. OS X does not use `\r` a.k.a. ASCII carriage return U+0D, and even if it did, a conforming C compiler on that platform would be required to call that value as `\n`. Backslash sequences are a confusing way to refer to binary bytes, not appropriate for a cross-platform site like cplusplus.com.

Comment: @bames53 @Potatoswatter Why would his editor on *windows* claim OSX endings?  Clearly it would state unix endings if they were `\n`?

Comment: Also, `\n` and `\r` are pretty well specced to be different values, even on a platform where `\r` is the line ending.

Comment: @AnthonySottile See my answer. It's an odd thing for an editor to say at all, and I suspect OP isn't giving an exact quote. However, given how long Classic Mac OS has been obsolete (think Windows Me), such files are uncommon in absolute terms

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Very helpful!

Comment: @Potatoswatter most editors will call files with `\r` terminated lines "Mac OS" because that's basically the only OS which was foolish enough to make that their default at any point in time.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm using sublime text and when I clicked on View->Line Endings it shows "Mac OS 9"

Comment: @AnthonySottile See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline . In the late 1970's when Apple chose `\r`, the landscape was different.

Comment: ^ @Potatoswatter exactly confirming my suspicions!  I imagine this file received by OP is particularly old (perhaps academia, or an old dataset)